# LCD connection problem

Tags: lcd

First of all, i have some problems with an lcd .
For a better understanding, the lcd datasheet could be found here:
https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/53098/DGF-12232-S1FBLY-325-17231-1006.pdf

i want to connect it to arduino mega but it has 20 pins and i can't figure it out how it should be connected.
Could someone help me ?

Comment: Looks pretty much like any other graphic LCD, so I'd start with that.

Comment: This display has a very old (20 year+) SED1520 display controller that is not really suited for low pin count microcontrollers like the Arduino. It needs a full parallel 8-bit data bus  and some (5) control signals, so you will need ~13 pins to connect it to your Arduino. It's not supported by common Arduino libraries so you would need to write your own low-level software to get it to display something. Frankly I would not bother and just buy a better supported (OLED or small TFT) I2C or SPI display instead.

Answer (score 1):

For those reading this answer prior to acquiring an LCD for an Arduino project, consider using a more common alpha / numeric LCD rather than a graphic LCD or GLCD.  Likely there will be more examples to follow as well as more software with more community support.

The linked to Graphical LCD (or GLCD) uses a [SED1520 controller](http://www.hpinfotech.ro/SED1520.pdf).  Searching the Arduino community resulted in finding [this openGLCD project](https://bitbucket.org/bperrybap/openglcd/wiki/Home).  There may be others.  Looking [here](https://bitbucket.org/bperrybap/openglcd/src/master/device/) (near the end of 2019) we see the comment "added custom sed1520 init routine to fully initialize sed1520 chips" next to the sed1520_Device.h file.  Likely this project supports GLCD modules which use the SED1520 chip.

With regards to wiring GLCD module, on page 19 of the specifications linked to in the question, the table in section 5.1 lists the description of the 20 GLCD pins.